# CRS is empty but GeoDataFrame plotted correctly when reading shapefile with GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas, nad83

I have a shapefile that I created in QGIS using the projection NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_Virginia_North_FIPS_4501_Ft_US.

When I load the shapefile into Python as a GeoDataFrame, it appears that the gdf doesn't have a crs.

The code sample:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

path = [shapefile path]

data = gpd.read_file(path)
data.crs
```

returns

```
{}
```

Does anyone have any insight? My guess is that I'm just going about getting the CRS the wrong way, but I can't tell what I should change.

Answer (score 3):

The [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) is a bundle of files. One of them is the *.prj*.

When [reading a shapefile with GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/main/geopandas/io/file.py#L204) and either:

- *.prj* is an empty file
- no *.prj* file at all

the output will be `None`.

So, in this case, check the origin of your shapefile or verify the process of exporting the shapefile with a projection.

Otherwise, it makes sense to apply the [`.set_crs()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html#geopandas-geodataframe-set-crs).

In your case case, it might be the [ESRI:102746](https://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/ims_/ArcXML_Guide/Support_files/elements/pcs.htm#102746):

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS

path = 'path/to/shapefile'

data = gpd.read_file(path)

crs = CRS.from_string('ESRI:102746')
data.set_crs(crs=crs)
```

---

**References:**

- [When are .prj files included with Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260740/when-are-prj-files-included-with-shapefiles)
- [Is there a standard for the specification of .prj files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114835/is-there-a-standard-for-the-specification-of-prj-files)
- [Fiona fails to write CRS to shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281447/fiona-fails-to-write-crs-to-shapefile)